# Usage of prepositions "a" and "in" in statements about places and directions

Tags: prepositions, etymology

The use of prepositions, showing direction and answering the questions "Dove?" and "Verso dove?", is usually explained with very few rules, such as

> *a* with the names of cities, *in* with the names of countries, big islands and regions

and then just as a list of cases to remember, e.g.:

> *a casa, a scuola, a teatro*, but *in banca, in chiesa, in centro*

Could anybody give me a hint about the etymology of these two prepositions, which might explain the difference in their use?

Comment: With big islands, I would use _a_: _sono a Long Island_, _sono alle Galappagos_. It is _sono in Sardegna_ because that is the name of the region too. How would the etymology help you understanding how to use those prepositions? Both comes from Latin, but that doesn't help much.

Comment: @kiamlaluno I know how and when to use them. I'm more interested in *why* use them this way. Language (any language!) is a stable structure. For a structure to be stable, it should rely on certain laws, some logic behind every part of the construction. The fact that we don't remember or don't pay attention to such logic doesn't mean that it didn't exist at the time when the language has been developing. I'm perfectly aware that it's not always possible to recover such logic after centuries, but if it's possible, may I try? :)

Comment: Yes, but you asked for the etymology, which means you are asking from which words _a_ and _in_ come from. For example, when asking the etymology of _batterio_, you would get that it comes from scientific Latin _bacterium_, from Greek _baktḗrion_, diminutive of _bàktron_. That doesn't help in understanding when _batterio_ is used instead of another word, nor does it say anything about those _laws_ behind the usage of a word.

Comment: I disagree on languages being stable structures, since neologisms are always possible. It's not always possible to get _laws_ about natural languages' grammar; otherwise, a program would be able to analyse a phrase and say if it is grammatically correct.

Comment: @kiamlaluno 1. "Etymology is the study of the history of words, their origins, and how their form and meaning have changed over time." If there was time when only *a* or only *in* had been used as a preposition of place, it's still the matter of etymology. 2. I don't say the languages are "rigid" structures, of course, they accept changes. But they *are* stable. Moreover, there are programs able to analyse the grammar rules--not perfect, but quite well.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The etymology of *a* and *in* is simple: they come from Latin *ad* and *in*.

This *partly* explains why we use both *a* and *in* to denote direction. But there's also *da* (which comes from Latin *de*) and probably only someone really expert in the history of Italian can explain the last preposition.

In Latin *ad* meant go towards some place, but not necessarily entering it. In [the entry *ad* of Lewis and Short](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0059:entry=ad) we find

> As antith. to ab (as in to ex), in a progressive order of relation, ad denotes, first, the direction toward an object; then the reaching of or attaining to it; and finally, the being at or near it.

Conversely, *in* implies entering: [the entry for *in*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0059:entry=in1) has

> I. in, within, on, upon, among, at; into, to, towards.
>   I. With abl.
>   [...]
>   II. With acc.
>   A. In space, with verbs of motion, into or to a place or thing (rarely with names of towns and small islands;

So the Italian usage with towns and small islands is a direct descendant from Latin. A small island is probably identified with its main village or port, so *in* was felt inappropriate. A big island like Sicily had many towns and a vast land, so *in* was better suited.

We have *vado a casa* because one's home is not really a building, but something more intimate. We can and do say *vado in casa*, for example when I'm in my garden and want to say I'm going into the house. Conversely, *vado in ufficio* or *in chiesa* because we enter a building.

My feeling is that with *scuola* and *teatro* we don't identify them with a building, so they're abstractions, unless a particular school or theater is specified; not with *cinema*, probably because it's a recent addition to the language. Here are some examples:

- vado a scuola, vado al liceo Fermi
- vado a teatro, vado al teatro alla Scala
- vado al cinema, vado al cinema Altino (not any more, actually, it has been closed for many years)

For countries it's normally *in*, but small countries often want *a*: *vado a San Marino* (but *nel Lichtenstein* and *nel Lussemburgo*).

---

**Side note.** As Mauro Vanetti brilliantly remarks in comments, it's not easy to know when an island is to be considered small. For instance, Cyprus is rather larger than Corsica, but we say

> *a Cipro* and *in Corsica*

so Cyprus is small and Corsica is big, according to the ‘rule’. Also Ceylon is considered small (although being much larger than Sicily, 65 610 km² against 25 711 km²), but it becomes a big island when called Sri Lanka. And *il Madagascar* follows neither pattern, because it wants the article: maybe, at 587 041 km², it's too big even for an island; but no, Greenland is even bigger (2 166 086 km²) and we say *in Groenlandia*. Other examples are *nel Borneo* (743 330 km²) and *a Sumatra* (473 481 km²): while Borneo is undoubtedly a big island, it's difficult to believe that Sumatra is small.

Toponyms are always a source for controversies, finding one's way in them is always a problem.

Comment: Fantastic. Thanks, @egreg!

Comment: This was a brilliant explanation indeed. Just a side remark: how big is a big island? Apparently, Corsica is a big island (_Vado in Corsica_) while Cyprus is small (_Vado a Cipro_). Unfortunately, Cyprus is larger than Corsica by 600 square kilometers! Another funny case is the island of Ceylon, since 1972 known as Sri Lanka. If you go to Ceylon, it's a small island even if it's 7 times larger than Corsica, but since 1972 it's become a large island... :-) I guess it's because Sri Lanka is perceived as a country and not just an island.

Comment: @MauroVanetti Good question! The only answer is probably “who knows?”; neither *Corsica* nor *Cipro* have an eponymous city. Another curious case is *il Madagascar*. Conversely, *Lussemburgo* is a town, but the state is called *il Lussemburgo*, whereas the same doesn't happen with *Andorra*. Another doubt can be about why we say *vado a teatro*, but *vado al cinema*.

Comment: [This link](http://www.accademiadellacrusca.it/it/lingua-italiana/consulenza-linguistica/domande-risposte/articoli-preposizioni-davanti-nomi-isole) may help, I suppose.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there is no real rule for *a* or *in* in Italian; it's something you learn.

There are some guidelines, but as you will see they don't cover all possible cases.

- Country, region, big isle: **In** - Abito in Italia, Vado in Sicilia
- City: **A** - Vado a Genova, a Milano, a Londra
- Own home: **A** - Vado a casa
- Someone's home: **Da** - Vado da Marco, da mia nonna, da un'amica
- With verbs: **A** - Vado a mangiare/a dormire/a studiare
- Professional offices:  **Dal/dalla** - Vado dal medico; vado
  dall'avvocato;
- Places with speficic role: **In** o **A**

  - al cinema, a teatro, a una mostra, a scuola
  - in chiesa, in ospedale, in clinica

Comment: Thanks, @mucio. It doesn't really answer the question, as I've asked _why_, not _how_ to use them, but many thanks for these examples.

Comment: _Sicilia_ is the name of the region too, that is why _in_ is used. Still, it's _vado alle Galapagos_, not _vado in Galapagos_.

Comment: @kiamlaluno I wrote "big isle", anyway Galapagos is an archipelago

Comment: @I.M. I think you will need something more that a SE website, the Italian language is not something that happened after the Latin, but the result of languages that were there before Latin and arrived during and after the Roman empire. In Latin "Vado a casa" is "eo domum", to explain this you probably need a couple of master thesis. This is why there is no rule or etymology of in or a, but you should find the etymology for each possible expression. And then you will find that sometimes a language can change just because it "sounds" better in a way instead of another.

Comment: @mucio Thanks for this comment, too. There are no languages that just happened after another language, as English doesn't come from Anglo-Saxon, etc. And yes, in most of the cases in most of the languages, it just "sounds better."