# Why do some words require articulated prepositions while others require simple prepositions?

Tags: word-usage, prepositions, articles

I found the following set of sentences in my Rosetta Stone program:

> Dove vuole andare? - Voglio andare in albergo.
>
> Dove volete andare? - Vogliamo andare a teatro.
>
> Dove vuoi andare? - Voglio andare allo stadio.
>
> Come vai a scuola?
>
> Come vai al lavoro?

Why does the `albergo`, `teatro`, and `scuola` not have an article, but the `stadio` and `lavoro` have? Is there any rule that some nouns take an article while others don't?

Also, does this depend on the specific word or on the specific usage of a word (i.e. do some words take an article sometimes while not on other times)?

Comment: They are not articles, they are all preposition.

https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preposizione

Comment: Possibly a  duplicate of http://italian.stackexchange.com/q/4079/707