# "Andare a" vs "andare in" - places

Tags: prepositions

Is there any general rule to decide between using the preposition "a" or "in" with "andare" and *places* ? Some examples:

- andare in biblioteca
- andare a scuola
- andare al parco
- andare al cinema
- andare al mercato
- andare all'aeroporto
- andare in ospedale
- andare in albergo
- andare in montagna
- andare al mare
- andare in spiaggia

The rules of using "in" for countries, states, regions, continents and big islands, "a" for cities and small islands and "da" when the place refers to a person (eg house/office of somebody) are clear and they are out of the scope of this question.

Comment: How can it be a duplicate if I am the creator of both questions ?

Comment: This question has already been answered many times in its various forms. Try to search for _andare and [preposition]_ in the search bar.

Comment: I *have* searched a previous answer before asking, but I could not find it. Could you point an answer which answers *the specific scope* of my question?

Comment: Indeed, the two questions are very similar.

Comment: https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/5661/why-do-some-words-require-articulated-prepositions-while-others-require-simple-p which is a duplicate of this https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/4079/preposition-a-or-al which can answer your question.

Comment: The two questions are about something else, but indeed the most voted answer of https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/4079/preposition-a-or-al ends up answering my question. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most rules about how to choose which preposition must be used with "andare" are already mentioned in your question. There are a few others:

- with a street or a square, use "in": Laura abita in via Buozzi.
- with a shop or a store, use "in": Devo andare in farmacia. However, if the name of the shop or store is followed by some specification, use the articulated preposition "a" or the articulated preposition "in": Ho comprato queste pillole alla farmacia dei Quattro Cantoni.

The cases which are not covered by these rules, such as almost all the examples in your question, must be learned by heart. A list with more cases can be found at [Preposition "a" or "al"?](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/4079/preposition-a-or-al)

Comment: “with a street or a square, use "in": Laura abita in via Buozzi.” This is actually very place-dependent: in Rome that sentence sounds either bureaucratic or Northern, and you'd more often say _Laura abita a via Buozzi_ or, for a more typical example, _...a viale Trastevere_ (_...in viale Trastevere_ sounds almost wrong to a Roman ear).

Comment: @DaG Very interesting. I would never use anything but *in* with road names, *a* sounds very wrong to me (I am from the North-East).

Comment: @DenisNardin: I perceive this alternation _a_ / _in_ as quite a strong a difference in Northern versus Central Italian in other contexts too. For instance, I hear Northern people saying such things as _vado in stazione_ or _lavoro in_ [company's name], while Central Italian uses _vado alla stazione_ or _lavoro a(lla)_ [company's name]. (I'd be interested in Southern Italian's uses; I'm less conversant with them.) (I know: I'm being quite unfair to all Italian speakers by vaguely dividing them in just a few large categories.)

Comment: @DaG Since I found this phenomenon intriguing I decided to [ask a question about it](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/11017/variazione-regionale-nelluso-delle-preposizioni-di-luogo). You are welcome to try to answer it with what you know about the difference between North and Center, although I hope someone else will chime in with a more refined analysis.

Comment: Good idea, @DenisNardin. I too hope in a some wide-ranging, sourced answer.