# Strutture con preposizioni semplici: quando e come diventano preposizioni articolate?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

Nella lingua italiana, ci sono molti costrutti con le preposizioni semplici "a" o "in". Per esempio:

> - Vado a casa.
> - Vado a scuola.
> - Vado a teatro.
> - Vado in farmacia.
> - Vado in biblioteca.
> - ecc.

Ho osservato che, in alcuni di questi casi, le preposizioni diventano la preposizione "a" articolata quando si aggiunge qualche specificazione, ma non so se sia sempre così. Ad esempio:

> - Vado all'altra casa.
> - Vado alla Scuola Ufficiale di Lingue di Barcellona.
> - Vado al Teatro alla Scala.
> - Vado alla farmacia dei Quattro Cantoni.

Le mie domande sono: si deve fare sempre così? Cioè, si devono cambiare le preposizioni semplici "a" e "in" nella preposizione "a" articolata quando il nome è seguito da qualche specificazione? Per esempio:

> - Vado alla biblioteca dell'università.

Si può usare anche la preposizione "in" articolata in alcuni casi? Per esempio, si potrebbe dire "Vado nella biblioteca dell'università"?

Comment: Trovi qualcosa a http://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/1192/usage-of-prepositions-a-and-in-in-statements-about-places-and-directions. Per *vado in farmacia* è lo stesso: non stai specificando *quale* farmacia, quindi stai parlando dell'astrazione della farmacia.

Comment: La mia domanda è su come si cambia la preposizione semplice nella preposizione articolata. Penso che non abbia risposta (perlomeno non una risposta completa) in quest'altra domanda che parla piuttosto della differenza tra "a" e "in".

Comment: Non ho votato per chiudere, infatti.

Comment: Ci ho pensato, e in realtà io non direi praticamente mai "alla biblioteca dell'università" ma "in biblioteca in università".
"Vado/lavoro in biblioteca a Como" non "vado/lavoro alla biblioteca di Como". Bella domanda.

Comment: Non sempre. Un esempio classico è "vai a quel paese".

Comment: @VitalijZadneprovskij: Ma in questo esempio non si direbbe "vai a paese" o "vado a paese".

Answer (score 3):

Se il complemento di moto a luogo retto dalle preposizione *a* e *in* è formato da un’*espressione definita*, allora sarà necessario usare la forma articolata di queste preposizioni. Gli esempi da Lei forniti sono sufficientemente indicativi:

> Vado **a casa**. ~ vado **all’altra casa**. (*non* *vado ad altra casa) 
>  Vado **in biblioteca**. ~ vado **alla
>   biblioteca dell’università**. (*non* *vado a biblioteca dell’università)

L’uso dell’articolo determinativo in riferimento a espressioni inerentemente definite è però soggetto ad alcune restrizioni:

> L’uso dell’articolo determinativo (definito) con nomi o sintagmi
>   nominali inerentemente definiti non è però sempre obbligatorio. Ad
>   es., il grado di accettabilità dell’articolo determinativo (definito)
>   **coi nomi propri di persona** varia secondo condizionamenti diatopici […]. Anche la combinabilità di articolo determinativo (definito) con
>   altri nomi propri (**nomi di marche o di industrie, nomi di popoli, di
>   nazioni**, ecc.) è soggetta a variazione […]. [*Enciclopedia dell’Italiano*, «[articolo](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/articolo_%28Enciclopedia_dell%27Italiano%29/)», grassetto mio)

Di norma, i nomi propri di persona non prendono mai l’articolo determinativo. Ci sono, è vero, differenze geografiche in quest’uso, come ricordato nel passo sopra citato, ma queste differenze non affiorano nella lingua modello, se non nel caso di consapevole riproduzione o imitazione di parlate locali. In quanto ai nomi di marche e organizzazioni, si può dire «Lavora *in RAI*» o «Lavora *alla RAI*», senza differenze di sorta.

Occorre tuttavia occuparsi di un’apparente eccezione. L’articolo determinativo si può trovare talvolta in contesti nei quali esso non è interpretabile né nel suo ruolo determinativo (perché non accompagna espressioni inerentemente definite), né in funzione anaforica (ripresa di un nome già introdotto nel discorso), né in funzione deittica (riferimento al contesto extralinguistico). Si tratta della cosiddetta referenza omoforica, ossia dell’uso dell’articolo per riferirsi a realtà del mondo esterno che si presume esser parte della conoscenza comune. Si veda quest’esempio:

> Non ha **la morosa** e sta tutto il tempo **al bar**.

In questo caso è evidente che l’articolo determinativo non è usato in riferimento a una precisa occorrenza discorsiva precedente, né a una precisa realtà extralinguistica, bensí allude a oggetti di conoscenza comune.

Sgombrato il campo da questi casi particolari, la regola che è stata accennata sopra — l’articolo si usa in genere con espressioni inerentemente definite — rimane valida.

In quanto alla Sua ultima domanda, c’è una differenza semantica tra *a* e *in* nell’espressione del moto: *a* indica una direzione verso la quale ci si muove; *in* il moto in luogo, ossia l’ingresso in un luogo. Pertanto, «Vado *alla* biblioteca dell’università» vuol dire che mi muovo verso quel luogo; «Vado *nella* biblioteca dell’università» significa invece che mi muovo verso la biblioteca e vi entro.

Answer (score 0):

Non so se c'è una regola generale, ma, come fai notare tu stessa negli esempi, quando chi parla suppone che l'interlocutore abbia bisogno di maggiori specifiche rispetto alla consuetudine allora si usa la preposizione articolata per specificare/determinare meglio quel che si vuol dire.
Esempi:
- "Vado a scuola" -> L'interlocutore capisce che vado alla solita scuola o alla scuola dell'obbligo, o che sono studente.
- "Vado alla Scuola Ufficiale di Lingue di Barcellona" -> Voglio che l'interlocutore sappia che vado in una scuola ben specifica.
Tornando a "Vado alla biblioteca dell'università" credo lo direi se solitamente andassi nella biblioteca sotto casa per chiarire che stavolta vado a quella dell'università, mentre direi "Vado in biblioteca all'università" se questa fosse la biblioteca che frequento in questo periodo.

Answer (score 0):

Vado a scuola -> Non ritengo necessario specificare quale scuola. Ci vado tutti i giorni. È LA scuola.

Vado alla Scuola Ufficiale di Lingue di Barcellona -> Ho bisogno di specificare QUALE scuola. È una scuola particolare e voglio comunicarti esattamente quale scuola è.

Posso anche dire "Vado alla scuola elementare" o "vado alla scuola superiore". In questo caso voglio indicare (specificare) quale tipo di scuola, dato che nel contesto potrebbe essere necessario.

Comment: Benvenuto su Italian.SE, @Nico! Penso che questo sia più o meno spiegato nel testo della propria domanda. Non trovo però risposta alle domande specifiche che ho fatto.