# Vado "al lavoro" oppure "a lavoro"

Tags: grammar, prepositions

Mi piacerebbe conoscere le origini di entrambe le forme (che a quanto parte risultano entrambe corrette) sebbene "vado a lavoro" è più tipicamente usato nel sud Italia.

Comment: Se si cercano le due espressioni con Google Ngram Viewer, *“vado a lavoro” non compare proprio (https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=vado+al+lavoro%2Cvado+a+lavoro&year_start=1800&year_end=2020&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=) e facendo l'analogo con “andare a/al lavoro” c'è una soverchiante maggioranza con “al”.

Comment: Puoi specificare cosa ti fa pensare che "vado a lavoro" sia corretto e più tipicamente del Sud? Tieni presente che se ti limiti ad una semplice ricerca in rete puoi trovare espressioni dialettali scritte in vari modi ed errori di battitura.

Comment: Sono del "Sud Italia" e non ho mai sentito nessuno dire "vado a lavoro".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tutti i sostantivi maschili ad occhio pare che vogliano "al/allo": 
vado al cinema, vado al bar, vado al lavoro, vado al mercato, vado allo stadio...

Potrei sbagliare, ma con il femminile le cose si complicano un po' e mi pare che ci siano delle eccezioni: vado a casa, ma vado alla casa di cura, vado a scuola, vado alla cerimonia, vado alla festa, vado alla sinfonia.

Non saprei nemmeno dire perché si va alle città (vado a Londra), ma si va dentro gli stati (vado in Inghilterra) :)

Direi che quando si usa 'a', si tratta di eccezioni, al fine di garantire una maggiore eufonia.

Comment: Veramente è così? Si dice "vado a teatro" o "vado a letto", no?

Comment: Hai trovato un'eccezione che, in quanto tale, non modifica la regola.

Comment: Una risposta piena di “ad occhio”, “potrei sbagliare”, “non saprei”, “direi che” può fornire utili spunti, ma non mi sembra molto risolutiva.

Comment: Credo che il genere del sostantivo non abbia proprio nessuna connessione. Sono già stati citati il teatro, il letto, si potrebbe citare _vado in ufficio_ e del resto si dice anche _vado in bagno_ o _vado al bagno_ (né _nel bagno_, né _a bagno_ che vuol dire un'altra cosa). _Vado a lavoro_ è un'espressione che molti usano, anche se può sembrare più strana. Aggiungo anche altri casi ambigui come _vado a mare_, _vado a fiume_. La regola, se c'è, dipende da tutt'altro.

Comment: Anche la teoria dell'eufonia mi sembra assolutamente infondata: _vado al cinema_ ma _vado a cena_. Non mi direte che _a ce_ suona tanto diverso da _a ci_.

Comment: sono più confuso che persuaso :) p.s.: "vado a fiume" non l'avevo mai sentita.

Comment: La caduta dell'articolo indica familiarità con un luogo, in alcuni posti dove si ha familiarità col mare o con un corso d'acqua si usa. Faccio un esempio dell'altro ieri con _a lago_: http://www.laprovinciadicomo.it/stories/como-citta/giardini-a-lago-al-buio-e-senza-sicurezza-il-comune-rifa-limpianto-di-illuminaz_1161922_11/

Comment: Decameron, sesta giornata, novella seconda: _- Adunque -, disse il famigliare - a cui mi manda? - Rispose Cisti: - Ad Arno. -_

Comment: @MauroVanetti quella è lingua volgare abbastanza arcaica, ed è pure linguaggio poetico. Ci mancherebbe che valgono le regole del 1200.

Comment: Certo, si dice da secoli e si dice tuttora, questo ci dà qualche indicazione sul fatto che sia un'espressione che in qualche modo risuona nella testa di molti. Ovviamente non significa che sia "giusta" (ma lo è :-) ).

Answer (score 4):

È corretto 'Vado al lavoro', al massimo si può usare 'Vado a lavorare'.

Credo che 'Vado a lavoro' sia una distorsione dialettale, ma sono convinto che qualcuno ti sappia dare maggiori informazioni al riguardo.

Comment: mhmh... e perchè non si dice "vado alla scuola"? ma "vado a scuola"?

Comment: @PolHallen: Perché le lingue naturali non sono orologi svizzeri. :-)

Comment: @Pol Hallen, inoltre in italiano si può dire "vado alla scuola" se di seguito stai specificando la scuola: "vado alla scuola dietro l'angolo" o "vado alla scuola professionale" ecc ecc.

Comment: A questo punto si tratta probabilmente di un influenza dialettale ma io non avrei mai usato "Vado al lavoro", mi suona malissimo al punto da sembrare scorretta. Credo che qui in Veneto (almeno nei dintorni di Treviso) si usi uniformemente "Vado a lavoro"

Comment: @Dennis Nardin: nel Veneto ci mangiamo quella L finale, ed il fatto che la parola che segue comincia con la L complica la cosa. Ma è dialettale, né più né meno di quando ci mangiamo tutte le doppie

Comment: @Erik Non è importante, ma non credo che sia tanto che ci mangiamo le *l*, quanto per somiglianza con *vado a casa*, *vado a letto*, *vado a nanna*, *vado a scuola*, *vado in ufficio* (e non *vado nell'ufficio*) etc.. (Inoltre il mio nome è *Denis* con una n sola, se no non mi arrivano notifiche ;))

Comment: @Denis Nardin autocorrettore :(

Comment: Anche se ci fossero usi diversi su base regionale, questo non significherebbe che sia "dialettale".

Comment: _vado alla scuola_ indica l'edificio, o la tipologia di Scuola, _vado a scuola_ indica l'attività, a seconda del contesto in senso più generale _sono giovane vado ancora a scuola_, o più specifico _domani non vado a scuola_.  _vado al lavoro_ indica uno specifico luogo di lavoro, _vado a lavoro_ indica più genericamente l'attività. Forse anche per  _vado al mare_ e _vado a mare_.

Answer (score 3):

Premessa: vivo in Lombardia, ho sentito dire molte volte *a lavoro* e non vedo perché considerarlo un errore. Si tratta di una variante della complicata questione dell'omissione dell'articolo determinativo per astrarre la funzione di un luogo/oggetto/individuo familiare.

L'esempio tipico è la casa: se parlo di casa mia, non metto l'articolo, è come se *casa* fosse il suo nome proprio. In effetti i bambini dicono *mamma* o *papà* come se fosse il nome dei genitori (lo si potrebbe anche scrivere con la maiuscola), uso che in genere resta tutta la vita, specie parlando con fratelli o con l'altro genitore, e viene facilmente esteso ad altri parenti. Questo non rende sbagliato dire *la mamma*, di solito mia mamma è la mia mamma. Però due gemelli che scoprono di essere stati adottati potrebbero dire una frase come questa:

> Caspiterina, Romolo: mamma non è veramente la nostra mamma!

Lo stesso vale per altri luoghi che diventano in qualche modo astratti, dei luoghi dello spirito. Vado *a teatro*, cioè mi reco là dove si fa teatro. Potremmo dire *a teatro in spiaggia* per parlare di uno spettacolo teatrale fatto all'aperto, senza che ci sia un vero teatro.

Se però due amanti si incontrano a notte fonda in un teatro e vengono scoperti, diremmo *Atti osceni nel teatro*, perché se dicessimo *Atti osceni a teatro* penseremmo che gli atti si siano consumati o sulla scena o al massimo tra il pubblico durante lo spettacolo. A proposito di atti osceni, *andare a letto con qualcuno* è possibile anche in assenza di veri e propri letti, controprova del fatto che senza articolo si coglie la funzione.

Ora, attenzione però: questa non è una regola per derivare espressioni valide, ma per interpretare espressioni esistenti. Non da ogni sostantivo con l'articolo si può estrarre la versione astratta, funzionale, senza articolo. Per esempio, in contrasto con *teatro*, non si può fare con *cinema*, che vuole sempre l'articolo. Qualcuno potrebbe anche provarci, dicendo che va *a cinema*, sicuramente sarebbe capito da tutti e si capirebbe anche in che senso ciò è leggermente diverso da andare *al cinema*, tuttavia sarebbe un uso insolito. Non credo che si possa stabilire una regola per cui le parole che indicano alcuni luoghi si sono sdoppiati in luogo con articolo e funzione senza articolo, mentre altri no: si tratta quasi di lessico più che di grammatica.

Arriviamo al dunque: si va al lavoro o si va a lavoro? Qua *lavoro* è metonimia per *ufficio* o *fabbrica* o *negozio* o *cantiere* ecc. E in effetti si va *in ufficio*, *in fabbrica*, *in negozio*, *in cantiere* (per misericordia non apriamo un altro capitolo dolente cioè quello dell'alternanza tra *in* e *a*). *Lavoro* è anche il contraltare di *casa*, quindi vado via *da casa* per andare *a lavoro*, torno *da lavoro* per andare *a casa*. Ecco perché non mi sembra strano che si dica anche senza articolo.

Se non agisce questo meccanismo di caduta dell'articolo, e in effetti pare che agisca in certe zone del Paese e non in altre, si torna alla regola generale e quindi, siccome stiamo parlando proprio di quel lavoro lì, di quello che faccio io, allora lo chiamo *il lavoro* e quindi quando vado a farlo *vado al lavoro*.

Siccome mi piacciono i casi limite, che spesso sono i più istruttivi, ora ne escogito un altro. Poniamo che io faccia due lavori, uno stabile in città e uno saltuario fuori città e in posti che cambiano (tra l'altro, è proprio così). Mi telefona la ragazza e chiede dove sono. Io mi trovo fuori città per il lavoro saltuario. Risposta:

> Sono a lavoro.

Mi verrebbe più naturale formulare così la risposta perché se avessi usato l'articolo avrebbe potuto pensare che mi trovassi nel mio solito ufficio (ossia, un po' paradossalmente, *in ufficio*, senza articolo). Così sto dicendo, più vagamente, che sto lavorando.

Answer (score 2):

Non mi risulta che le forme "vado a lavoro", "vado a mare" e "vado a fiume" siano accettate come corrette. Non ci sono riferimenti letterari di rilievo e proprio questi diventano il metro di valutazione vista la dichiarata incapacità di risalire alle ragioni dell'affermazione di una preposizione invece di un'altra. Si dice "vado a teatro", ma "vado al cinema", "vado al lavoro", ma "vado in ufficio o in fabbrica", "vado al bar", ma "vado in edicola", "vado a scuola", ma "vado in chiesa". È invece più evidente, nei casi in cui è prevalsa la preposizione semplice, come l'apparire dell'articolo assuma l'incisività di un aggettivo dimostrativo: "vado a scuola", ma "vado alla scuola dietro l'angolo", "vado a teatro", ma "vado al teatro che mi hai suggerito".

Comment: Benvenuto su Italian.SE, @Giuseppe! Grazie della risposta. Potresti fare anche un'occhiata a questa mia domanda: http://italian.stackexchange.com/q/5196/707?

Comment: ma anche _vado a teatro come mi hai suggerito (per superare la depressione)_