# How can I translate these conditional sentences?

Tags: grammar, conditional-mood

- If I weren't going on my business trip next week, I would have accepted that new assignment at work.

(I'm wondering especially about how to translate "weren't going", because in English we're using present continuous with a future meaning).

- If I weren't going to be busy tomorrow...
- I'm not going to the concert tonight, but if I were going...

Comment: Welcome! You can render it with “dovere”: *se non dovessi andare in viaggio d'affari la settimana prossima, avrei accettato il nuovo incarico al lavoro*.

Comment: Even if it is not much correct, especially in spoken language it has become customary to use the future tense inside the conditional sentence.
e.g. _"se non sarò occupato domani..."_

Comment: I would use the past subjunctive *Se non fossi in viaggio di lavoro domani, avrei accettato il nuovo...*. @egreg's solution is probably better though

Comment: Grazie! And these two: If I weren't going to be busy tomorrow...
I'm not going to the concert tonight, but if I were going...

Comment: Wouldn't "se non sarò occupato domani" be "If I'm not busy tomorrow", which is quite different from "If I weren't going to be busy tomorrow"?

Comment: @Ngrammer I would use the same construction of my previous comment: *Se domani non fossi occupato, andrei al concerto*. Note that while it is technically a past tense, here we are using it to express a sense of impossibility rather than a temporal placement. Compare [this article](http://aulalingue.scuola.zanichelli.it/benvenuti/2012/03/29/il-periodo-ipotetico-dellirrealta/)

Comment: In which sense would “*se non sarò occupato...*” be “not much correct”, @RiccardoDeContardi? I'd categorise it as a normale “periodo ipotetico della realtà” (unless the speaker intended to imply that being free is quite unlikely, and so he would phrase it differently).

Comment: @DaG I suspect that the reason is that the sentence in the question implies that the speaker will not be free (otherwise it would be *If I am not going on my business trip* or even more strongly *Unless I'm going on my business trip*).

Comment: @DaG I think that the subjunctive tense would be more appropriate than the future tense... in my experience the usage of the future as I wrote, is more informal/spoken language related. Maybe I could be wrong...

Comment: @DenisNardin: It's likely. Then it's not a matter of being more or less correct grammatically, but that the Italian version with the indicative mood is a mistranslation.

Comment: @egreg: Puoi mettere il tuo commento come risposta?

Comment: @DenisNardin: Puoi mettere i tuoi commenti come risposta?

Answer (score 4):

A literal translation could be with [*se non fosse che*](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_italiano/S/se_non.shtml); a better rendition might be

> se non dovessi andare in viaggio d’affari la settimana prossima, avrei
>   accettato (accetterei) il nuovo incarico al lavoro

However also

> se non fosse che andrò in viaggio d’affari…

would fit.

Something like *If I weren't going to be busy tomorrow, I should come to the concert* can be treated the same way: *Verrei al concerto, se non fossi così impegnato domani*; the adverb *domani* already conveys the idea of future.

Answer (score 2):

This is the most literal translation I can make:

> Se la settimana prossima non andassi in viaggio d'affari, avrei accettato quel nuovo incarico al lavoro.

Here I use the past subjunctive tense, but to express irreality rather than temporal placement. If, in addition to irreality I had to express also a past tense, I would use the *congiuntivo trapassato*

> Se il mese scorso non fossi andato in viaggio d'affari, non avrei ricevuto quell'aumento

(*If I hadn't gone in a business trip last month, I would not have received that salary increase*).

Comment: Mi sono permesso due piccole modifiche, Denis. Su “settimana prossima”, vedi [qui](http://www.treccani.it/lingua_italiana/domande_e_risposte/grammatica/grammatica_280.html); su “a lavoro”, mi suona strano (era un refuso?), ma magari da qualche parte si dice. Forse dovremmo affrontare queste questioni in altrettante domande.

Comment: Anche a me suonava molto strano "Se settimana prossima...", ma io non sono italiana, quindi stavo per scrivere un commento chiedendo se mancasse l'articolo "la" in questa frase.

Comment: @DaG In realtà entrambe erano esattamente come le avrei dette io... Ma può darsi che sia un regionalismo. Almeno su *a lavoro* sono abbastanza sicuro di averlo sempre usato così (similmente a *sono a casa*). Google ngram mi dà torto ma sono molto sorpreso.

Comment: Mmmmm... Fatto interessante per porre un'altra domanda!

Comment: Stavo per chiederlo come una domanda ma vedo che [ce n'è già una](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/6493/vado-al-lavoro-oppure-a-lavoro). Che devo dire? Farò un sondaggio tra parenti e conoscenti per capire se si tratti di un uso dialettale o se in qualche modo sono riuscito ad attraversare un numero ragguardevole di anni di scuola senza mai rendermene conto...

Comment: Beh... sarebbe interessante sapere se alcune varianti regionali tendono a sopprimere l'articolo determinativo in certe espressioni.

Answer (score -1):

I would translate in

> Se non sarai stato in viaggio di lavoro la prossima settimana, avrei accettato quel nuovo compito a lavoro.

Comment: “sarai”? “a lavoro”? Due volte “lavoro” nel giro di poche parole? Sicuro?